# What intelligence is the narrator referring to?

Tags: terrorism

I watched this political movie, Vice (2018), and the narrator said these words:

> Abu Musab Al-Zarqawi had taken his fame from Powell's UN speech and
>   turned it into his own new thing. The Islamic State of Iraq and
>   Levant......or ISIS. And because **that intelligence** somehow found
>   itself on the bottom of a stack of papers...Zarqawi had a whole year
>   to just do whatever the hell he wanted.

What specific document it's referring to?

Comment: Are you asking what the word means in this context, or what specific document it's referring to?

Comment: what specific document it's referring to?

Comment: I think this might be more suited to Movies.SE. I'm not saying it's off-topic here, just that it's a better fit for there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [transcript here](https://www.imzxn.com/2019%20Vice%20English.php), it looks like it's referring to:

> ... On another note, I've been handed a credible report
>   of a small terrorist enclave in Northeastern Iraq. If we're going to invade we suggest taking it out before.
>
> ...
>
> That classified document
>   described a terrorist named Abu Musab Al-Zarqawi
>   who had started as a drug dealer and pimp
>   before becoming fully radicalized in a Jordanian prison.
>   Zarqawi went to meet Bin Laden in Afghanistan.

I'm not sure if there's a specific real-world document that's being referred to, or whether it's a stand-in for whatever internal reports were written internally by the CIA and are still classified.